# Javascript How do I filter search results based on multiple input words?

Tags: java, javascript, reactjs

I want to filter search results based on the input. so far I only filter starting with the first word typed and Im not sure how to filter based on (possible) multiple words/inputs.
If I search for example: "funny stories" and one of the book name is stories, I want to return that as a match, just like when input is "funny". With my current code I would only return said book if I start typing funny.

```
const filteredSuggestions = suggestions
    .filter(({name}) => {
            const match = name.substr(0, searchInput.length);
            return match && match.toLowerCase() === searchInput.toLowerCase();
});
```

I tried (its not working):

```
const filteredSuggestions = suggestions
    .filter(({name}) => {
         const nameArr = name.split(" ");
        nameArr.map(name => {
            const match = name.substr(0, searchInput.length);
            return match && match.toLowerCase() === searchInput.toLowerCase();
        })
});
```

Comment: `nameArr.map`   your filter needs to return a boolean, so what your after here is `return nameArray.some(name => ..)` or `return nameArray.every(name =>...)`  depending on if you want an OR or  AND..    ps. Don't forget the `return`, JS doesn't use implicit returns unless it's an arrow function without `{}`..

Comment: thank you, I replaced it like you said with some and returned it and now its working as I want it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `includes` string method to filter the search.
Here is the approach

```js
const filteredSuggestions = suggestions
    .filter(({name}) => {
            return name?.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
});
```

This will match all words including the input at any position.

But if you want to match only those words whose first letter is matching with the input value then you can use RegExp.

For example

```js
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${userInput}`, "i");
const filteredSuggestions = suggestions
    .filter(({name}) => {
            return regex.test(result)
});
```

In this case, if your search input is 's' it will return both "Funny stories", and "Serious stories". As it will match the first letter of any word in the search result.

But if you want to match only the first letter of the first word of search results then you can use the below RegExp

```
const regex = new RegExp(`^${userInput}`, "i");
```

In this case, if your search input is 's' it will only return "Serious stories".

Comment: thank you. with your code I would search all words including the input at any position, however, I want to only return matches where inputs start with typed letter. so in my example, I would like to show ''funny stories" when user either types "f" or "s", however, I do not want to show said book when user types a letter like "u" (as its not in the beginning)

Comment: In that case, you can use regExp of javascript. I have edited my answer with RegExp. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about using **[startsWith function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)**:

```js
const books = [
  'funny stories',
  'tales',
  'science',
  'medicine'
],
display = document.getElementById('display'),
input = document.getElementById('input'),
results = document.getElementById('results');
  
display.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(books);

function onSearch(event)
{
  const value = event.target.value.trim();

  if( value )
  {
    const filtered = books.filter(book => book.startsWith(value));
    results.innerHTML = filtered.length ? JSON.stringify(filtered) : '';
  }
  else
  {
    results.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="display">

</div>

<br>

<input id="input" onkeyup="onSearch(event)" type="text">

<br> <br>

<div id="results">

</div>
```